# How to change the values on the view onclick of button without reloading of the page using mvc

Tags: asp.net

i m trying to create a view in which the header of page contain some button and according to the button click the content on the page should be change.
should i use partial view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ajax and webapi.
e.g.

```html
<span id="test_span">default text</span>
<input type=button value="change text by webapi" />
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#test_span").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:'webapi url',
                success: function(data){
                    $("#test_span").text(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```